# Acessing Controller and Action name at _initVars() Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I hope I had made me clear in my question!

I would like to access the getControllerName() and getActionName() inside _initVars(). This is what I'm trying to do:

```
    protected function _initVars() 
    {

        $this->bootstrap('layout');
        $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
        $view = $layout->getView();
        $view->theme = 'MY_THEME';


        $this->bootstrap('frontController');
        $front = $this->getResource('frontController');


        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($front->getRequest());
        echo '</pre>';
        exit;

        return $view;

    }
```

I'm getting no response, the fields controllername and actionname are returning empty, this is what I get in the return:

```
Zend_Controller_Front Object
(
    [_baseUrl:protected] => 
    [_controllerDir:protected] => 
    [_dispatcher:protected] => Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard Object
        (
            [_curDirectory:protected] => 
            [_curModule:protected] => default
            [_controllerDirectory:protected] => Array
                (
                    [default] => /var/www/proj_rodrigo/application/controllers
                )

            [_defaultAction:protected] => index
            [_defaultController:protected] => index
            [_defaultModule:protected] => default
            [_frontController:protected] => 
            [_invokeParams:protected] => Array
                (
                )
```

It's just a part of the code, the necessary things are there, in the old schema of Zend I could be capable to do it calling Zend_Front_Controller, but now I don't know more how to use it.

Appreciate any help!
Best regards and sorry for my BAD English.

To fix this issue, I add the postDispatche at my plugin:

public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) 
{

```
$bootstrap = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap');
$layout = $bootstrap->getResource('layout');
$view = $layout->getView();

$view->controller = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$view->action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
```

}

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this code is in the `Bootstrap` class. Since `Bootstrap` code runs before the routing - in, fact this stage is where routing is often *defined* - the controller and action are not yet determined.

If you want to get that info, you need to create a [front-controller plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) implementing an early-running method - that runs *after* routing has set the controller and action - like `routeShutdown()` or `dispatchLoopStartup()`or `preDispatch()`.

Check out: [ZF Dispatch Overview](http://nethands.de/download/zenddispatch_en.pdf) (PDF)

Comment: You're welcome. I guess my assumption of an early-running plugin was wrong. Glad you got it all working. Cheers!